# How to link a Excel sheet in a Word document

Tags: excel, ms-word

I want to know how to link (with an Word Hyperlink) a specific sheet in my word document.
I have already tried this :

- `E:\x\y\workbook.xlsx#'mySheet'`
- `E:\x\y\workbook.xlsx#mySheet`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You want to add the excel within the word document? Please be more specific

Comment: No i just want to have an hyperlink how can open a specific sheet in my word document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at a couple of tutorials ([here](http://shaunakelly.com/word/word-and-excel/excelhyperlinks.html) and [here](https://word.tips.net/T000305_Hyperlinking_to_a_Specific_Excel_Worksheet.php)) you should be able to do it the way you have but it didn't work for me either.

It did work, however, if you include a cell reference along with the sheet. Try this:

```
E:\x\y\workbook.xlsx#'mySheet'!A1
```

You can also use a [Named Range](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) to select a specific cell or range with:

```
E:\x\y\workbook.xlsx#NamedRange
```

The named range one also worked when I tested it.